# SignalR Core Angular SSR - Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, module, signalr

We just upgraded our API from .NET Framework to .NET Core. We migrated to SignalR Core. So, we had to upgrade our SignalR client on our Angular front as well. No problem. Everything works on local. But when we deploy on our Azure App Service, we get this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:276222:21)
    at webpack_require (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.@microsoft/signalr (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:264546:18)
    at webpack_require (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:248813:30)
    at Object../src/app/shared/services/signalR/signarRService.ts (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:263030:17)
    at webpack_require (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:248813:30)
```

I checked and we can find signalr.js files in dist/browser. We're on the last package version. Everything related found on internet didn't help even a bit.

With SignalR Framework version, everything worked just fine.

It has been one week we're working on it. But still, we don't understand why it keeps happening. 
What we tried :

- To downgrade signalR package to a lower version
- When uninstalled, everything works.
- Upgrade npm and node version
- Copy signalr.js in assets and use it instead (of course a bad idea)
- I checked dotnet/signalr github for every issues but nothing did a thing
- and I stopped counting...

Maybe there is something special with Azure. We can't say. So we need help.

Thanks !

Our angular service

```
import ...;
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnectionState } from '@microsoft/signalr';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

    private readonly frontHub: string = 'FrontHub';
    private readonly BroadCastAuditStatus: string = 'BroadCastAuditStatus';
    private readonly SubscribeToAuditStatutUpdate: string = 'SubscribeToAuditStatutUpdate';

    private hubConnection: HubConnection;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    public listenToAuditedAccountStatus(accountIds: Array<string>, userId: number) {
        const subscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequest = new SubscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequestDto(userId, accountIds);
        if (this.hubConnection &&
            this.hubConnection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected) {
            this.subscribeToAuditStatutUpdate(subscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequest);
        } else {
            this.startConnection().then(() => {
                this.subscribeToAuditStatutUpdate(subscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequest);
            });
        }
    }

    private startConnection() {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl(environment.webSignalR + '/' + this.frontHub)
          .build();

        this.hubConnection.on(this.BroadCastAuditStatus, (googleAdsAccountDto: GoogleAdsAccountDTO) => {
            this.store.dispatch(DoUpdateStatusAccountAuditedAction({ payload: googleAdsAccountDto }));
        });

        return this.hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
    }

    private subscribeToAuditStatutUpdate = (subscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequest: SubscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequestDto) => {
        this.hubConnection.invoke(this.SubscribeToAuditStatutUpdate, subscribeAccountStatusUpdateRequest);
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "seiso",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:fr": "ng serve --aot --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18nFormat=xlf --locale=fr",
    "build:fr": "ng build --prod --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18nFormat=xlf --locale=fr",
    "extract": "ng xi18n --outputPath=src/locale",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "build:ssr:staging": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-staging && npm run webpack:server",
    "build:ssr:testing": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-testing && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run seiso:server:production",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles-staging": "ng build --configuration=staging && ng run seiso:server:staging",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles-testing": "ng build --configuration=testing && ng run seiso:server:testing",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "prepare-azure-app": "copy web.config dist && cd dist && mkdir dist && mv browser server ./dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
    "@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router": "~2.0.1",
    "@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router-http-loader": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "~8.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~8.1.1",
    "@ngx-cache/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.8.0",
    "core-js": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "localize-router-lazy-universal-module-loader": "1.0.0-ntr",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.2.0",
    "ngx-countdown": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.9",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "~5.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Did you enable web socket on the azure app service you deployed too?

Comment: I'm not a node/angular/front end person, but here's something that could help. Try to download the version you've deployed and run it locally. It would be easier to debug / find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed that.
I found that not one but three dependencies where missing. So I added a task in my pipeline Azure DevOps, just after "npm install" : npm install request eventsource ws.

If your node version is too old on your app service, "ws" won't compile. So in my Azure App Service Configurations, I set "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" from 6.3.1 to 10.16.3.

Reboot your app service and relaunch your pipeline.

I hope it will help people with this issue !

[Task "npm install request eventsource ws"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW7HS.png)